# Interval confidence of a poisson distribution for different sample sizes

Tags: poisson-distribution, confidence-interval

Assume I have an infinite sequence of natural numbers $n_1, \ldots$ where each number comes from a poisson distribution $P(k)$ with $k$ unknown.

I want to estimate $k$: I take the first $N$ numbers $n_1, \ldots, n_N$ and calculate its mean, $k_0$, and I have a 95% probability that the actual $k$ is in the interval $k_0 \pm 1.96\sqrt{k_0/N}$.

If instead of $N$ numbers I take $5*N$ numbers and calculate a new mean $k_1$, shouldn't the probability of $k$ being in the interval $k_1\pm 1.96\sqrt{k_1/(5*N)}$ be higher than 95% since I'm using more data?

I mean, I expect to trust more a mean taken from 10000000 samples than from 10, but it seems the maths above doesn't want to say it.

Comment: Where are you getting $\sqrt{k_0/2}$ from? The standard deviation of $k_0$ is $\sqrt{k/N}$ (which you can estimate with the plug-in estimate $\sqrt{k_0/N}$).

Comment: @angryavian fixed. I don't know why I wrote `/ 2` to be honest.

Comment: Do you mean $\sqrt{k_1/(5N)}$ for the second interval or $\sqrt{k_1/N}$?

Comment: @angryavian yes, fixed again. Sorry for the slip.

Comment: Why do you think the second interval should have a higher probability of containing the true mean? The width of the interval is defined in such a way that the probability is 95% (assuming the normal approximation is exact).

Comment: @angryavian You are right. I was very confused. I wrote what I didn't mean (`/ N`), but my question was based on what I wrote. Now that the second formula is fixed it's obvious that the second interval in shorter than the first. So with same probability I have a more precise interval now since I'm more data, which does make total sense.

Comment: Great, glad this is clear to you now!